# Pytorch LSTM not using GPU

Tags: gpu, lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to train a pytorch LSTM model connected with couple of MLP layers. The model is coded as follows:

```
class RNNBlock(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, in_dim, hidden_dim, num_layer=1, dropout=0):
    super(RNNBlock, self).__init__()

    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
    self.num_layer = num_layer

    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(in_dim, hidden_dim, num_layer, dropout)

def forward(self, onehot, length):
    batch_size = onehot.shape[0]

    h_in = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.num_layer, batch_size, self.hidden_dim))
    c_in = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.num_layer, batch_size, self.hidden_dim))
    packed = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(onehot, length, batch_first=True)

    output, (h_out, c_out) = self.lstm(packed, (h_in, c_in))
    unpacked, unpacked_length = nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(output, batch_first=True)
    vectors = list()
    for i, vector in enumerate(unpacked):
        vectors.append(unpacked[i, unpacked_length[i]-1, :].view(1, -1))
    out = torch.cat(vectors, 0)
    return out

class Predictor(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, in_dim, out_dim, act=None):
    super(Predictor, self).__init__()

    self.linear = nn.Linear(in_dim, out_dim)
    nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.linear.weight)
    self.activation = act

def forward(self, x):
    out = self.linear(x)
    if self.activation != None:
        out = self.activation(out)
    return out

class RNNNet(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, args):
    super(RNNNet, self).__init__()

    self.rnnBlock = RNNBlock(args.in_dim, args.hidden_dim, args.num_layer, args.dropout)
    self.pred1 = Predictor(args.hidden_dim, args.pred_dim1, act=nn.ReLU())
    self.pred2 = Predictor(args.pred_dim1, args.pred_dim2, act=nn.ReLU())
    self.pred3 = Predictor(args.pred_dim2, args.out_dim)

def forward(self, onehot, length):
    out = self.rnnBlock(onehot, length)
    out = self.pred1(out)
    out = self.pred2(out)
    out = self.pred3(out)
    return out
```

and this is my train and experiment functions

```
def train(model, device, optimizer, criterion, data_train, bar, args):
epoch_train_loss = 0
epoch_train_mae = 0

for i, batch in enumerate(data_train):
    list_onehot = torch.tensor(batch[0]).cuda().float()
    list_length = torch.tensor(batch[1]).cuda()
    list_logP = torch.tensor(batch[2]).cuda().float()
    # Sort onehot tensor with respect to the sequence length.
    list_length, list_index = torch.sort(list_length, descending=True)
    list_length.cuda()
    list_index.cuda()
    list_onehot = torch.Tensor([list_onehot.tolist()[i] for i in list_index]).cuda().float()

    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    list_pred_logP = model(list_onehot, list_length).squeeze().cuda()
    list_pred_logP.require_grad = False

    train_loss = criterion(list_pred_logP, list_logP)
    train_mae = mean_absolute_error(list_pred_logP.tolist(), list_logP.tolist())
    epoch_train_loss += train_loss.item()
    epoch_train_mae += train_mae

    train_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    bar.update(len(list_onehot))

epoch_train_loss /= len(data_train)
epoch_train_mae /= len(data_train)

return model, epoch_train_loss, epoch_train_mae

def experiment(dict_partition, device, bar, args):
time_start = time.time()

model = RNNNet(args)
model.cuda()

if args.optim == 'Adam':
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(),
                           lr=args.lr,
                           weight_decay=args.l2_coef)
elif args.optim == 'RMSprop':
    optimizer = optim.RMSprop(model.parameters(),
                           lr=args.lr,
                           weight_decay=args.l2_coef)
elif args.optim == 'SGD':
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(),
                           lr=args.lr,
                           weight_decay=args.l2_coef)
else:
    assert False, 'Undefined Optimizer Type'

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=args.step_size, gamma=args.gamma)

list_train_loss = list()
list_val_loss = list()
list_train_mae = list()
list_val_mae = list()

data_train = DataLoader(dict_partition['train'], batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=args.shuffle)
data_val = DataLoader(dict_partition['val'], batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=args.shuffle)

for epoch in range(args.epoch):
    scheduler.step()

    model, train_loss, train_mae = train(model, device, optimizer, criterion, data_train, bar, args)
    list_train_loss.append(train_loss)
    list_train_mae.append(train_mae)

    mode, val_loss, val_mae = validate(model, device, criterion, data_val, bar, args)
    list_val_loss.append(val_loss)
    list_val_mae.append(val_mae)

data_test = DataLoader(dict_partition['test'], batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=args.shuffle)

mae, std, logP_total, pred_logP_total = test(model, device, data_test, args)

time_end = time.time()
time_required = time_end - time_start

args.list_train_loss = list_train_loss
args.list_val_loss = list_val_loss
args.list_train_mae = list_train_mae
args.list_val_mae = list_val_mae
args.logP_total = logP_total
args.pred_logP_total = pred_logP_total
args.mae = mae
args.std = std
args.time_required = time_required

return args
```

The list_onehot and list_length tensors are loaded from the DataLoader and uploaded to GPU. Then, to use packed sequence as input, I’ve sorted the both list_onehot and list_length and uploaded to GPU. The model was uploaded to GPU and h_in, c_in tensors and packed sequence object were also uploaded to the GPU. However, when I try to run this code, it does not use GPU but only use CPU. What should I do to use GPU to train this model?